# Incomplete dependencies for Kotlin in build.gradle

Tags: kotlin, gradle, junit

I'm new to Kotlin and JUnit.

I tried following this documentation https://kotlinlang.org/docs/jvm-test-using-junit.html and added
`testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test'` and added this

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

but it seems like there's something that needs to be changed/added in my build.gradle

I can't annotate my new function with `@Test`

Is there anything that I missed that needs to be added?

Thank you!

Comment: What error are you getting specifically?

Comment: @xjcl no errors but I think I miss some dependencies that's not stated in their docs (or I missed)